# (Wampserver) Error while loading a CSS file

Tags: css, wampserver

I got this error: `Error: styleSheet.exceptions is undefined` while trying to load a css file; both path and file are correct.
I just dowloaded wampserver and ran it then I loaded the page and the error persists.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/global.css">
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Where is that error thrown? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: It's shown in the console and I don't know what to try since I'm not used to use wampserver: I searched answers on the Internet but found nothing about this error. I also tried to restart wampserver.

Comment: In which console? Is that an error thrown by Javascript?

Comment: From the web console; I don't know where it comes from since the only thing I found is this message.